# List posts in a category grouped by other categories?

Tags: taxonomy, categories, multi-taxonomy-query

I have posts of stores and restaurants in my area.  Each post is marked by category of type (e.g. Restaurant, store) and town.

What I am trying to do is create a page for each town (with intro text and photos enter into the page ui) and then a loop of Posts in that town's category grouped by the other categories.

Ideally, I'd like to get the current page's slug, or last part of the url to use for the post query: as in "http://mysite.com/towns/mayberry" would display all posts in the mayberry category grouped by the other tags.

So my page is

Mayberry
some content

Listings:
Restaurants (in mayberry only)
- item
- item

Hotels (in mayberry only)
- item
- item

Is this possible?